# Problems adding sound to buttons Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity

One of the projects I'm working on for my android development class is build a baseball app.  I want to add the players walkup song to a radio button and the stats to another button.  I've got the general layout completed, but I'm having issues getting the mp3 playing.  I spent about 2 hours last night and time with the instructor today and wasn't able to find the issue.  I know there is a world of people smarter than me so any help you can provide would be wonderful.

Carpenter.class

```
package net.androidbootcamp.cardinals;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;


public class Carpenter extends Activity {

    RadioButton btmarp;
    int playing;
    MediaPlayer mpmarp;
    Button.OnClickListener bmarp = (new Button.OnClickListener);


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //TODO

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.carpenter);
        btmarp.setOnClickListener(bmarp);
        btmarp = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMarp);
        mpmarp = new MediaPlayer();
        mpmarp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.marp);
        playing = 0;


        Button btnmarp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCarpenter);


        btnmarp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/c/carpema01.shtml"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Todo
                switch (playing) {
                    case 0:
                        mpmarp.start();
                        playing = 1;
                        btmarp.setText("Long Hot Summer Day - Turnpike Troubadours");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mpmarp.pause();
                        playing = 0;
                        btmarp.setText("Long Hot Summer Day - Turnpike Troubadours");
                        break;

                }
            };
    }


}
```

Carpenter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/cardsbackground2">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/marp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/marp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnText"
        android:id="@+id/btnCarpenter"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnMarp"
        android:id="@+id/radCarpenter"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCarpenter"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem ? Music not playing or button can't be clicked ? And you need to move bmarp initialization before btmarp = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMarp);

Comment: The music isn't playing when I click it.  By initialization do you mean the
'btmarp.setOnClickListener(bmarp);'

Comment: I was referring to this `Button.OnClickListener bmarp = (new Button.OnClickListener() {...` . You can just put this outside onCreate and make it a field variable. And remove that extra `(`

Comment: Do you mean adding this part?
`RadioButton btmarp;
    int playing;
    MediaPlayer mpmarp;`

As `Button.OnClickListener bmarp = (new Button.OnClickListener)`

Comment: Yes, and remove the unnecessary `(` and then update your question with the new code. Actually with the code you currently have I doubt it would run.

Comment: This doesn't even compile...

Comment: Yes I know I'm trying to figure out where my syntax is wrong to compile it :/

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for sound.  Hope it helps some...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    ImageButton button6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    final ImageButton stopButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.gijane1);
            player.start();

        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.rounds);
            player.start();
        }
    });
```